# Python - prime lister not displaying results or any errors

Tags: python

This is just a small segment of my code but I believe this is the part not working. So the user takes a low and high and finds all the prime number inbetween. But when I run this in IDLE not only is there no response, but there are no errors?! Can somebody please help.

^^^^^^ THIS WAS SOLVED THANKS GUYS ^^^^^^

New Question!

How would I change rangemax to make this print infinitly?

```
print('Prints all prime numbers between certain numbers.')    
rangemin = rangelowdef()
rangemax = rangehighdef() 

if rangemax != 'inf':
    for num in range(rangemin, rangemax + 1):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(1, num):
                if num%i == 0:
                    break

            else:
                print(num)
```

Comment: To test a `num` for its primeness, you should starting from 2, instead of 1. Because every number is divisible by 1, but not by 2 (for example, odd numbers)

Comment: Then you can mark the answer as accepted, by ticking the mark left of the answer :). If you have a new question, post a new question, instead of editing the old one.

Comment: To answer your second question, you can change `for num in range(rangemin, rangemax + 1):` with `for num in xrange(int(1e10)):`. It will take enough time to get to 1e10. `xrange` is a generator, as opposed to `range`. With range you can hit the memory limit, with xrange not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num % 1` is always 0. That is because it is an integer (from the `range` function). So the loop breaks immediately and nothing gets printed.

Comment: Okay thanks, I made a small typ0. 1 was meant to be i. And range(0, num), the 0 was changed to 1 to prevent divided by 0 error.  @mathias711 but this still does produce any outcome!!